# Scope always get the same relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to make a relation ship bt condition...

I'm try like this:

Model:

```
public function page_link()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Link::class, 'page_id', 'user_id')->inRandomOrder()->Select('links.id', 'links.title', 'links.photo', 'links.country', 'links.friendly_url', 'links.clicks', 'links.description', 'links.suggestions', 'links.count_comments', 'links.url', 'links.shares', 'links.page_id', 'links.tag_id', 'links.created_at')->where('sponsored', 0)->where('scheduled', 0)>where('status', 1)->take(3)->orderBy('id','desc');
}

public function user_share()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Share::class, 'user_id', 'user_id')->inRandomOrder()->Select('id', 'link_id', 'user_id', 'shared_in', 'content', 'created_at')->take(3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('type', '=', 0);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function scopeProfile($query)
{
    return $query
        ->when($this->type == 0, function($q)
            {
                return $q->with('user_share.link.page')->with('user')->with('user_share.link.tag');
            })
            ->when($this->type == 1, function($q)
            {
                 return $q->with('page_link');
            })
            ->when($this->type == 2, function($q) 
            {
                 return $q->with('group_link');
           });
}
```

Controller:

```
 $feed = Feed::Profile()->where('follower_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->take(10)
                ->get();
```

But ALL the results, even the type 1 or 2 returns "user_links" relation. I don't know whats happening.

Someone can help me?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `$this->type` to be in this case? I'm pretty sure it returns `null` in all cases. For starters, you could (should!) compare with `===` and see if it still fetches the `user_links` relationship.

Comment: With === return none relation everytime.

Comment: Exactly. I assume you expect `$this->type` to be the value of `type` column. But it's not since you'd have to instantiate the model first to be able to get the value. And you're calling it in a query builder, not an instantiated model. It won't work that way.